# Spring Boot 2.0 Intercepting the HandlerMethod of a Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am midway through upgrading from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.0 and have noticed I have started getting class cast errors in my `HandlerInterceptor`s.

For example, in one `HandlerInterceptor` I look if the controller method/endpoint is annotated with `@AdminOnly` to restrict access to certain endpoints.

```
@Component
public class AdminOnlyInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse, Object handler) {
        HandlerMethod hm = (HandlerMethod) handler;
        Method method = hm.getMethod();
        if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(RestController.class) && (method.isAnnotationPresent(AdminOnly.class) || method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(AdminOnly.class))) {
            // Some Logic returning true or false
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This worked in Spring Boot `1.5.x`.

After upgrading I now get the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod
```

I couldn't find anything relevant in the [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes). How can I upgrade but keep the interceptor above working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears Spring Boot 2.x Interceptors now also process Static Resource requests, so these now need to be manually excluded when registering the interceptor like below:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final AdminOnlyInterceptor adminInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public ControllerConfiguration(AdminInterceptor adminInterceptor) {
        this.adminInterceptor = adminInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(adminInterceptor)
                .addPathPatterns("/rest-api-root/**"); // White list paths
                //.excludePathPatterns("/static-resource-root/**"); // Black list paths
    }
}
```

Comment: my css and js file exist under resource/public !  How can I exclude it ?

Comment: I would imagine you can use the `excludePathPatterns("public/**")`

Comment: Thanks man ! You save my days !! I got solution by adding `/common/**,/js/**,/css/**` :)

Comment: In Spring boot by default. What is the path that should be excluded?